# Unable to install Google cloud SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I am trying to install google cloud SDK on my Windows 10 machine. the installer stops at the below error. SDK also install python and set auto path in Environment variable right? on my system not already install python. so before install SDK require to set Python path in enviroment varible?

```
Downloading Google Cloud SDK core.
Extracting Google Cloud SDK core.
Create Google Cloud SDK bat file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\cloud_env.bat
Installing components.
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
ERROR: gcloud failed to load: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
    gcloud_main = _import_gcloud_main()
    import googlecloudsdk.gcloud_main
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import cli
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import backend
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import parser_extensions
    from googlecloudsdk.core.updater import update_manager
    from googlecloudsdk.core.updater import installers
    from googlecloudsdk.core import local_file_adapter
    import requests
    from . import utils
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
    from http.cookies import Morsel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or problems with your Python interpreter.
Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 or 3.5+ executable:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe
If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 or 3.5+ executable.
If you are still experiencing problems, please reinstall the Cloud SDK using the instructions here:
    https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\bootstrapping.py", line 44, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.credentials import store as c_store
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\credentials\store.py", line 40, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core import requests
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\requests.py", line 26, in <module>
    from google.auth.transport import requests as google_auth_requests
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\google\auth\transport\requests.py", line 26, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\requests\__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\requests\compat.py", line 60, in <module>
    from http.cookies import Morsel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Failed to install.
```

Comment: What's your current version of Python?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere in my system currently not install any versionn of python

Comment: As per the message on terminal:
Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 or 3.5+ executable:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe
If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 or 3.5+ executable.

Can you verify if Python2.7 or Python3+ is pointed correctly, esle you can set environment variable CLOUDSDK_PYTHON to the python.exe path installed in your system